# Battery information acting weird

Tags: 14.04, power-management, battery

I am having a battery problem. Many people had similar syndromes one way or another, but I just couldn't get a good solution. My battery has been showing 100% after updating. If I unplug AC and use it for a time which is usually the time to run out a "really 100%" battery, it just shutdown w/o notice while still showing 100% batt. I have tried to restart power indicator, not helpful. So I checked with `upower --dump`, and get

```
Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_AC0
  native-path:          AC0
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Tue 16 Aug 2016 03:28:22 PM PDT (1052 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  line-power
    online:             yes

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               ASUSTek
  model:                UX31-35
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Tue 16 Aug 2016 03:45:27 PM PDT (27 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               fully-charged
    energy:              41.461 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         41.461 Wh
    energy-full-design:  47.88 Wh
    energy-rate:         4.144 W
    voltage:             8.285 V
    percentage:          100%
    capacity:            86.4766%
    technology:          lithium-ion

Daemon:
  daemon-version:  0.9.23
  can-suspend:     yes
  can-hibernate:   yes
  on-battery:      no
  on-low-battery:  no
  lid-is-closed:   no
  lid-is-present:  yes
  is-docked:       yes
```

Which I guess do say that the battery is being recognized 100%. Then I check power statistics history from `/var/lib/upower` (also from power manager GUI), the data is all 0 since the trouble-making update. I deleted the history files and restarted `upower` (also tried reinstall). The history files were regenerated like this, e.g. history-time-full-UX31-35-47.dat

```
1471374419  0.000   unknown
1471375898  0.000   unknown
1471377435  0.000   unknown
1471378760  0.000   unknown
1471384495  0.000   unknown
1471386178  0.000   unknown
```

, and the problem is not solved. Then I tried to play around with dconftool-2. I found that if I set `use_profile_time` to *false*, my laptop shutdown when I unplug AC, while the battery is being 100%. If it's set *true*, it does switch to battery power when unplugged, though the percentage is not change. And in either case, if I didn't plug in AC, I couldn't turn on my laptop with power bottom.

For additional information, I am using **ASUS Zenbook UX31E**, Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and changed to a new battery last month (but gotten no problem for weeks before update).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used ASUS Zenbook (but in another model) as well with Ubuntu 16.04 (4.4 kernel) and the battery applet works fine. Ubuntu 14.04.5 (4.4 kernel) has been released earlier this month. I will suggest to update your kernel to have 4.4 kernel stack, no matter which 14.04.x you have used.

You may be interested in the distribution vs. [kernel enablement stack details](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack).

Answer (score 0):

I've got it solved. I found the [file](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html) which turns on hibernate is gone, but in most places the hibernate option is still there. So I added it back. Now the battery is back to normal and showing 1%. I guess even though I've had the AC on most of the time for the past few hours, since it recognized the battery 100%, it's not charging it. So the voltage is low and makes everything acts like there's no battery.